# Coldfusion execute a stored procedure without refreshing the page?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a stored procedure with a "selection" parameter

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="MyProcedure" datasource="MyDataSource">
  <cfprocparam type="in" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#selection#" null="no">
</cfstoredproc>
```

I have a select box where the user can select the box, and I would like to use jquery to "call" the stored procedure:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#selectbox').change(function() {
            // update my #selection# variable
                        // run the stored procedure again (the one above)
        });
    });
```

Is there a way to do this? I know it's mixing client and server side code but I can't refresh the page because there are multiple forms on the page...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#selectbox').change(function() {
            $.get('pathToYourStoredProcCFM.cfm?selectVal=' + $(this).val(), function (res) {

               // if you need to handle the response to the stored proc 
               // on the client side (which was output in your CFM code), do so here
               // (the response from CF is stored in the "res" variable)

            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: hmmm...if I am am changing content on the same page can I just do something like $.get('?selectVal=')

Comment: You'll have to make a trip back to the server in any case.  You could (in theory) call back to the same page that you originally loaded, although that sounds like a bad idea to me.  You should just isolate your stored proc call in a separate file, like I demoed.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies a lot actually.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need create a .cfm page with stored procedure in it and use an AJAX call to execute the stored proc.

storedProc.cfm

```
<cfparam name="URL.selection" />

<cfstoredproc procedure="MyProcedure" datasource="MyDataSource">
  <cfprocparam type="in" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#URL.selection#" null="no" />
</cfstoredproc>

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#selectbox').change(function() {
            // update my #selection# variable
            $.get("storedProc.cfm", { selection: $(this).val() } );        
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put your Stored Proc call into a seperate CFM file for your jquery to call.  You can't reference back to the one called on your page.